# Usar base de datos en xamarin

Tags: android, c#, sqlite, xamarin

Quería ver si me podían ayudar, actualmente tengo una aplicación para escritorio en C#, pero ahora se desea migrar esa aplicación hacia Android utilizando xamarin.

de aquí la pregunta si es posible la base de datos ya creada y funcionando, se podría utilizar esta misma en xamarin, la base de datos esta creada en SQLite.

lo que deseo saber mayormente es que si me evitaría poner en el código de nuevo la creación de las tablas y la BD

gracias.

Comment: En principio debería servirte sin problemas. De hecho, la base de datos nativa en Android es Sqlite, con lo que no deberías tener que modificar nada.

Comment: Bienvenido.Altair., te saludamos y te damos la bienvenida al sitio!, te invito a realizar el [tour] para 
conocer el funcionamiento básico del sitio y obtener tu primera 
[medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Con respecto a la realización de preguntas que estas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas excelentes respuestas, **es muy importante leer [ask]**, por lo tanto **te sugiero modificar tu pregunta, agregar lo que has realizado, más información, etc**, saludos!